# Problem downloading files with boost asio, junk in output file

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, asio

I'm trying to download any files from server - images, text/html, zip etc. But somehow I have some trash in the beginning and at the end of my output file.

```
#include "dependencies.h"

asio::streambuf response_;
std::istream is(&response_);
std::ofstream file("file.html", std::ios::out);

void readHeader(asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket>& socket);
void asyncRead(asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket>& socket);

void readStatus(asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket>& socket) {

    asio::async_read_until(socket, response_, "\r\n", [&](boost::system::error_code ec, size_t length) {
        if (!ec) {
            std::string header;
            is >> header;
            std::cout << "Protocol: " << header << '\n';
            std::string status_code;
            std::string status;
            is >> status_code;
            std::cout << "Status: " << status_code << '\n';
            std::string status_message;
            std::getline(is, status_message);

            readHeader(socket);
        }
        else if (ec != asio::error::eof) {
            std::cout << "[Status code] Error: " << ec.message() << '\n';
        }
    });
}

void readHeader(asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket>& socket) {

    asio::async_read_until(socket, response_, "\r\n\r\n", [&](boost::system::error_code ec, size_t length) {
        if (!ec) {
            std::string status_message;
            while (getline(is, status_message) && status_message != "\r")
                std::cout << status_message << '\n';

            asyncRead(socket);
        }
        else if (ec != asio::error::eof) {
            std::cout << "[Header message] Error: " << ec.message() << '\n';
        }
        });
}

void asyncRead(asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket>& socket) {
    asio::async_read(socket, response_, asio::transfer_at_least(1), [&](const boost::system::error_code ec, size_t length) {
        if (!ec) {
            file << &response_;

            asyncRead(socket);
        }
        else if (ec != asio::error::eof) {
            std::cout << "[Async reading] Error: " << ec.what() << std::endl;
        }
    });
}

int main(int args, const char* argv[]) {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    boost::system::error_code ec;
    asio::io_context context;
    asio::ssl::context sslContext(asio::ssl::context::method::sslv23_client);
    sslContext.set_default_verify_paths();
    asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket> socket(context, sslContext);

    //https://codeload.github.com/ERHZAN/NRM-Launcher/zip/refs/heads/main
    boost::urls::url url = boost::urls::url_view("https://en.cppreference.com/w/");
    std::string path = url.path();
    std::string host = url.host();
    std::string scheme = url.scheme();

    asio::streambuf request_;
    std::ostream os(&request_);
    os << "GET " << path << " HTTP/1.1" << "\r\n";
    os << "Host: " << host << "\r\n";
    os << "Accept: */*\r\n";
    os << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

    tcp::resolver resolver(context);
    tcp::resolver::query query(host, "https");
    resolver.async_resolve(query, [&](const boost::system::error_code& ec, tcp::resolver::iterator ep_iterator) {
        if (!ec) {
            socket.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer);
            socket.set_verify_callback([&](bool preverified, boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx) {
                char subject_name[256];
                X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
                X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);
                std::cout << "Verifying " << subject_name << "\n";

                return true;
            });

            socket.lowest_layer().async_connect(ep_iterator->endpoint(), [&](const boost::system::error_code& ec) {
                if (!ec) {
                    socket.async_handshake(asio::ssl::stream_base::handshake_type::client, [&](const boost::system::error_code& ec) {
                        if (!ec) {
                            asio::async_write(socket, request_, [&](const boost::system::error_code ec, size_t length) {
                                if (!ec) {
                                    readStatus(socket);
                                }
                                else {
                                    std::cout << ec.what() << std::endl;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            std::cout << ec.what() << std::endl;
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "[Connection] Error: " << ec.what() << std::endl;
                }
                });
        }
    });
    context.run();

    return 0;
}
```

And my output file is:

```
ab5b

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="client-nojs">
i've deleted all html here for your convenience
</html>


0
```

Answer (score 1):

It's [chunk encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

> Each chunk is preceded by its size in bytes. The transmission ends
> when a zero-length chunk is received. The chunked keyword in the
> Transfer-Encoding header is used to indicate chunked transfer.
>
> [...]
>
> Each chunk starts with the number of octets of the data it embeds
> expressed as a hexadecimal number in ASCII followed by optional
> parameters (chunk extension) and a terminating ␍␊ sequence, followed
> by the chunk data. The chunk is terminated by ␍␊.

Perhaps try a library which handles HTTP, such as Boost Beast, which will take care of that for you. Or try the solutions at [How to tell the HTTP server to not send chunked encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31969990/how-to-tell-the-http-server-to-not-send-chunked-encoding): Namely, specify HTTP/1.0.